# Windows fread unexpected behavior

Tags: winapi, fread

So fread is behaving unexpectedly on Win7 x64.

```
file = fopen(path, "rb");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
buffer = malloc(fileSize);
length = fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, file);
```

fread will return 1 byte as being read whereas (ferror and feof both return 0)

```
length = fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, file);
```

fread will return the same number of bytes read as fileSize. MSDN says "The fread function reads up to count items of size bytes from the input stream and stores them in buffer." Which I interpret as meaning that that either piece of code should read the same amount of data. Does anyone know why fread isnt working as I expect it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do read the same amount of data. The number of bytes read is the `size` parameter times the `count` parameter. What is returned is the count of items read.

So in the first case you asked for 1 item of size fileSize and it returned 1.
In the second case you asked for fileSize items of size 1 and it returned fileSize.

Answer (score 1):

[`fread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs(v=vs.71).aspx) returns "the number of full items actually read", not the number of bytes read.

With `fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, file);` you're reading one item of size `fileSize` (and `fread` will thus return 1 on success) whereas with `fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, file);` you're reading `fileSize` items of size 1 and it will return the number of bytes read (as you're expecting).